# How to determine UIWebView height based on content inside a variable height UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

I have a `UITableView` cell that is going to have a variable size depending on it's content (potentially several lines of text).

Since it appears that `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called before I layout the cell, I just guess the correct height by calling `[NSString sizeWithFont]` on my text string. Is there a better way to set the height after I've laid out the text in the cell and have an idea of exactly what size it should be?

My problem is each cell contains a `UIWebView` with different (statically loaded) content I can't figure out how to calculate the proper height based on the content. Is there a way to do this? I've tried things like this:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       WebViewCell *cell = (WebViewCell*)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       [cell setNeedsLayout];
       [cell layoutIfNeeded];
       return cell.bounds.size.height;
    }
```

The cells themselves are loaded from a nib, which is simply a `UITableViewCell` containing a `UIWebView`. (It would also be fine if the cells just adjusted themselves to the largest of the html content, though variable height would be nicer).

Comment: Find the string height dynamically using "boundingRect" in your "heightForRowAtIndexPath" then return that height. hope it will work

Comment: Use this tutorial to do that http://www.samrayner.com/posts/dynamic-tableview-cells. I don't like the idea of UIWebView repeated in every cell. The UIWebView consumes lot of memory, https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25526.

Comment: - (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView: tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
return cell.bounds.size.height; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath { 
      UITableViewCell   *cell = [self tableView: tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath]; 
      return cell.bounds.size.height; 
}
```